# Is it too expensive to add and remove event listeners on every call of my React custom hook? How to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here's my situation:

I've got a custom hook, called `useClick`, which gets an HTML `element` and a `callback` as input, attaches a `click` **event listener** to that `element`, and sets the `callback` as the **event handler**.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    if (myState === 3) {
      console.log("I will only count until 3...");
      return;
    }
    setMyState(prevState => prevState + 1);
  }

  useClick(buttonRef, handleClick);

  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={buttonRef}>Update counter</button>
      {"Counter value is: " + myState}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**useClick.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

function useClick(element, callback) {
  console.log("Inside useClick...");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Inside useClick useEffect...");
    const button = element.current;

    if (button !== null) {
      console.log("Attaching event handler...");
      button.addEventListener("click", callback);
    }
    return () => {
      if (button !== null) {
        console.log("Removing event handler...");
        button.removeEventListener("click", callback);
      }
    };
  }, [element, callback]);
}

export default useClick;
```

Note that with the code above, **I'll be adding and removing the event listener on every call of this hook.**

And I would very much like to **only add on mount and remove on dismount.** Instead of adding and removing on every call.

Even though I'm using this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  // Same code as above
},[element,callback]);  // ONLY RUN THIS WHEN 'element' OR 'callback' CHANGES
```

The problem with that is that even though `element` (**ref**) will remain the same across all renders, `callback` (**which is the handleClick function from App**) will change on every render. So I end up adding and removing the handlers on every render anyway.

I also can't transform `handleCLick` into a `useCallback`, because it depends on the state `myState` variable that changes on every render and my `useCallback` would still be recreated on every render (when `myState` changes) and the problem would continue.

```
const handleClick = useCallback(()=> {
  if (myState === 3) {
    console.log("I will only count until 3...");
    return;
  }
  setMyState(prevState => prevState + 1);
},[myState]); // THIS WILL CHANGE ON EVERY RENDER!
```

**QUESTION:**

[Example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jv3481j2yy)

Should I worry about removing and attaching even listeners on every render? Or is this really **not expensive at all** and has **no chance of hurting my performance**? It there a way to avoid it?

Comment: It may be because the example is somehow constructed but why do you need `useClick` in the first place when your can directly attach an onclick handler to the `<button>` via the `onClick` prop?

Comment: Simplified version of my real case. What I'm actually doing is a `useSwipe` for a carousel and the `callback` is a function called `changeImage` that should be aware of the `selected` state in order to stop user from swiping to an image index that is over my `props.images` array size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store the current callback in a ref and have a static callback for the event listener that only calls the current callback:

```
function useClick(element, callback) {
    console.log('Inside useClick...');

    const callbackRef = useRef(callback);

    useEffect(() => {
        callbackRef.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    const callbackWrapper = useCallback(props => callbackRef.current(props), []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Inside useClick useEffect...');
        const button = element.current;

        if (button !== null) {
            console.log('Attaching event handler...');
            button.addEventListener('click', callbackWrapper);
        }
        return () => {
            if (button !== null) {
                console.log('Removing event handler...');
                button.removeEventListener('click', callbackWrapper);
            }
        };
    }, [element, callbackWrapper]);
}
```

Working example:

[image: Edit 7wxqxwx1rj]